# davmail and JAVA INSTALLED MANUALLY

Tags: ubuntu, email, java, smtp, thunderbird

I'm trying to install davmail,
I've already install JAVA manually (tar.gz file).  After trying with the [ppa:webupd8team](http://www.enqlu.com/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-78-jdk-and.html) repo and not having good results. Had to clean a lot of files packages and so on.
Anyhow when trying to install davmail I'm getting this error

```
$ sudo dpkg -i davmail_4.4.1-2225-1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package davmail.
(Reading database ... 174785 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack davmail_4.4.1-2225-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking davmail (4.4.1-2225-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of davmail:
 davmail depends on openjdk-7-jre | openjdk-6-jre | oracle-java7-jre | sun-java6-jre; however:
  Package openjdk-7-jre is not installed.
  Package openjdk-6-jre is not installed.
  Package oracle-java7-jre is not installed.
  Package sun-java6-jre is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package davmail (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 davmail
```

And JAVA is configured

```
$ java -version 
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_55

$ which java
/usr/bin/java

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_55/
```

Is there a way to tell davmail that we already have JAVA installed?
or a workaround for this problem?

The update-alternatives option is configured as well.

```
$ update-alternatives --list java
/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java

$ update-alternatives --display java
java - auto mode
  link currently points to /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java
/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java - priority 100
Current 'best' version is '/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java'.

$ update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick and dirty solution, but you can tell `dpkg` not to check that dependencies are installed using the `--force-depends` option.

```
# This will install davmail regardless of of whether or not its dependencies
# are installed
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends davmail_4.4.1-2225-1_all.deb
```

Note that there is a warning in the manpage for this option :

```
   --force-things, --no-force-things, --refuse-things

          Force  or  refuse  (no-force and refuse mean the same thing) 
          to do some things. things is a comma separated list of
          things specified below. --force-help displays a message
          describing them.  Things marked  with  (*)  are  forced  by
          default.

          Warning: These options are mostly intended to be used by 
          experts only. Using them without fully understanding their
          effects may break your whole system.

          [...]
          depends: Turn all dependency problems into warnings.
```

---

Although it is not necessary to solve your immediate issue, note that when installing Java manually, if you goal is to install the "official" [Oracle distribution of Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp?locale=en), you should use `make-jpkg` to turn the Oracle `tar.gz` archive into a .deb package (See this [Debian wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage) for more information) :

```
make-jpkg jre-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo dpkg -i oracle-java7-jre_7u55_amd64.deb
```

This allows the Java package to register with the [Debian alternative system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) and let the system know you have a Java Environment installed and avoid dependency problems when installing packages that depend on Java.

Comment: I've already have update-alternatives configured, I also do like the option of building the package so I'm going to give it a try.